# Vuetify.js: how to cancel v-stepper-step header click when active form is invalid

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, v-stepper

I'm using a [v-stepper](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/steppers/#usage) from Vuetify.

What I want is:

- when the user click on a stepper step (in the header) I block the `click event` if the active form isn't valid

I've managed to do so but by setting the `click` listener on the `span` element:

```html
<v-stepper-step :key="step.id" :step="step.id" :rules="[() => !!step.valid]" :editable="currentStepId !== step.id && currentStep.valid">
  <span @click="headerClick" v-html="step.name"></span>
</v-stepper-step>
```

This works well, the click is cancelled and that's exactly what I want.
Here is [a live demo](https://codepen.io/cyrilf/pen/dyZMjgW?editors=1010) you can interact with.

**My issue is:**

It **only** works on the label, not the full clickable area.

I would like the entire stepper-step button to call this method.
But if I attach the `@click` listener on the `v-stepper-step` then it's too late, I can't cancel the click event (by doing `e.stopPropagation`).

Is there a way for me to do so?
[demo code](https://codepen.io/cyrilf/pen/dyZMjgW?editors=1010)

Thanks!

Comment: I tried your demo and it looks like your `editable` prop is just wrong. making it return false will not allow step to be changed.

Comment: I don't want it to return false all the time. Only when the active form is invalid (which works nicely once the $form.validate() return false) But clicking on the header change the bad before call my $form.validate()

Comment: hey, @CyrilF  why you are calling two different methods for the header and continue button? is it not possible to call same method in header too like.   <span @click="goToStep(step.id)" class="v-stepper-step-clickable"  v-html="step.name"></span>

Comment: @NileshMishra yes I could use the same method. But my goal is to cancel the click. The `headerClick` function gets an $event as a param so I can cancel the click with `event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: @CyrilF here is the link which I want to convey to you. https://codepen.io/nilesh9836/pen/GROqJaq?editors=1010

Comment: I see. But that's doesn't solve my issue. My problem is that when you click on the number "2", it goes to the next step without validating. But when you click on the text "All my requests" it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit unclear what you want to do exactly, but taking @click to the whole  makes it so the headerCLick function behave exatly how it does when the click is on the label, yet you can click anywhere on the header (which I take for granted is what you mean by "the full clickable area").

```
  <v-stepper-header @click="headerClick">
    <template v-for="step in steps">
      <v-stepper-step :key="step.id" :step="step.id" :rules="[() => !!step.valid]" edit-icon="$complete" :complete="currentStepId > step.id" :editable="currentStepId !== step.id && currentStep.valid">
        <span class="v-stepper-step-clickable" v-html="step.name"></span>
      </v-stepper-step>
      <v-divider :key="`divider-${step.id}`" v-if="step.id < lastStep"></v-divider>
    </template>
  </v-stepper-header>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. This isn't what I'm looking for. I want the `@click="headerClick"` to be on the `v-stepper-step` AND if the form isn't valid I cancel the click. But the cancelling doesn't work. It seems like the js click event is bubbling up so I'm too late in the call chain.